# ElasticSearch GeoDistance Range

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

With the upgrading of ElasticSearch (from 2.x to 6.3) we have lost functionality of using a min max range for our search.

Previously we were using this to create a "Donut search". We didn't want objects super close, but between the ranges.

Just probing to see if there is any possible way to do this in the newer version. Had a look through docs and can't see anything that will help.

```
f.GeoDistanceRange(x => x
Field(s => s.GeoLocation)
.Location(new Nest.GeoLocation(filter.SubjectLatitude.Value, 
filter.SubjectLongitude.Value))
.GreaterThanOrEqualTo(Nest.Distance.Kilometers(_distanceMin))
.LessThanOrEqualTo(Nest.Distance.Kilometers(_distanceMax)));
```

Comment: Would Geo Distance aggregation with a nested Top Hits aggregation work for your use case?

Comment: Thanks Russ, Exactly what i needed to use.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

A GeoDistance Aggregation with a nested Top hits Aggregation was the solution as Russ Cam had suggested. (Note: The ranges linq is there so i only search the bucket i need depending on which Min / Max values were entered (including nulls)

```
        if (_isSubjectGeocoded && (filter.DistanceMax.HasValue || filter.DistanceMin.HasValue))
        {
             search = search.Aggregations(a =>
             a.GeoDistance("sale_geo_distance_agg", g =>
             g.Field(s => s.GeoLocation)
             .Origin(filter.SubjectLatitude.Value, filter.SubjectLongitude.Value)
             .Unit(Nest.DistanceUnit.Kilometers)
             .Ranges(
                     r => !filter.DistanceMin.HasValue ? 
                                  r.To(_distanceMax) : 
                                  !filter.DistanceMax.HasValue ?                         
                                        r.From(_distanceMin) : 
                                           r.From(_distanceMin).To(_distanceMax)
              ).Aggregations(top => 
              top.TopHits("top_geodistance_hits", hits => hits
              .Size(_take)
              .From(_skip))))
         );
     }
```

I needed to apply this later with

```
        if (_isSubjectGeocoded && (filter.DistanceMax.HasValue || filter.DistanceMin.HasValue))
        {
            var _geoBuckets = _sales.Aggregations.GeoDistance("sale_geo_distance_agg").Buckets;
            Nest.RangeBucket _bucket = _geoBuckets.First();
            _totalCount = (int)_bucket.DocCount;
            var _bucketHits = _bucket.TopHits("top_geodistance_hits").Documents<SaleSearch>().Select(x => x.SaleId);
            _saleDocuments = _saleDocuments.Where(s => _bucketHits.Contains(s.SaleId)).Select(s => s);
        }
```

My only issue after that was that we originally had the page limits to 25/50/100/200/500
Now that i've implemented the top hits, i am lowering it to 25/50/100 as top hits only supports up to 100 without needing the change in settings in elastic (plus it's overkill for us anyway. Paging always works)

Hopefully this helps anyone else that encounters it. Although i did ramble a bit :D